# How a PC can ping two diferent PCs with the same ip address in different vlans?

Tags: networking, vlan

I have a question about VLANs and how they work.

here is the scenario;

I have a VLAN named vlan10 with PC1 and PC2 in it

- *The IP address of PC1: 10.10.10.10*
- *The IP address of PC2: 10.10.10.20*

and a VLAN named VLAN 20 with pc3 and pc4 in it

- *The IP address of PC3: 10.10.10.10*
- *The IP address of PC4: 10.10.10.20*

and they are connected to a switch and a router like this

[image: VLAN with the same ip address]

Can PC1 ping IP address 10.10.10.20 in VLAN 20 which is IP address for PC4 in VLAN 20?
or because we have the same IP address in VLAN 10, PC1 can not ping the PC4 in VLAN 20?

Answer (score 0):

Each PC matches an outgoing packet's destination address to its own subnet and talks to the destination directly. Even if you tried working around that using the router, the router would reject duplicate subnet addresses across different interfaces.

Whether duplicate addresses actually exist in the VLANs is irrelevant. When the destination address belongs to the sender's local subnet that's the end of the story.

Btw: you should take care to note the subnet prefix lengths, I'm assuming you use 10.10.10.0/24 (doesn't change the answer though).